# Xcode: How to integrate SymbollicC++ library in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode5

When I add this library in my project and try to build my app then it gives the following Errors:

```
  Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:  
  "Number<double>::Number(double const&)", referenced from:  
  Log::simplify() const in functions.o  
  Power::simplify() const in functions.o   
  "Number<int>::Number(int const&)", referenced from:  
  operator+(Symbolic const&, int const&) in symbolicc++.o  
  operator-(Symbolic const&) in symbolicc++.o  
  operator/(Symbolic const&, Symbolic const&) in symbolicc++.o  
  sqrt(Symbolic const&) in symbolicc++.o  
  Symbolic zero<Symbolic>(Symbolic) in symbolicc++.o  
  Product::simplify() const in product.o  
  integrate(Symbolic const&, Symbolic const&) in integrate.o  
  ...  
 ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7  
 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Are u added QuartzCore framework into your project?

Comment: @vishnu entirely irrelevant. did you even read the error message? the linker errors have nothing to do with QuartzCore.

Comment: add armv7 and armv7s only in the valid architecture as well as architecture section of the game and cocos2d-x project. (in both project and target section build settings)

Comment: http://www.acnenomor.com/3682238p1/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-x8664-error-when-linking-opencv-in-xcode

Comment: @vishnu I add armv7 and armv7s in the valid architecture of project and target also but it not works

Comment: This library run well on devices as well as Xcode simulator but failed in making build